# LTspice, Sallen & Key low pass filter + Low pass filter order 1

Tags: filter, ltspice, low-pass, sallen-key

First of all, sorry for my English, it isn't my native language.

I want to cascade a first order low pass filter and a low pass Sallen and Key structure in order to get my bandwidth at 30 Hz (Fc = 30 Hz).

So, I tried to calculate FC of my first filter (order 1) with C = 22n and R = 240K (E12 series for C and E24 series for R).

With that, I'm supposed to have -3dB at 30.14 Hz.

So, after that, I calculate my FC for my second filter (Sallen & Key structure, low frequency pass). I have used C2 = 1/2C1 (you can find a schematic below) and R1 = R2.

I made an Excel spreadsheet to calculate delta FC with E12 Capacitor and E24 or E12 resistor and that's what I get:

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

But when I try to simulate my filter on LTspice XVII, FC isn't at 30 Hz (approximately) but next to 20 Hz.

Is that normal? (It's the first time I try to do that, I'm a beginner.)

Here is my schematic on LTspice:

[image: Filter]

And here is my simulation result:

- In Dark Blue, it's INPUT
- In light Green, it's OUTPUT

[image: Simulation]

Comment: That's due to the loading effect: the output of the first filter (1st order) is influenced by the input of the second (2nd order). Move the RC filter after the opamp, optionally add a buffer. Why do you have those awkward supply connections? Non-symmetrical supply for the opamp, 5 V instead of ground?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thanks for your respons.
I'll try to move my RC filter.
For the awkward supply connections, it's my specification from my boss so I can't tell you (I'll ask him today).

Comment: The problem with those supplies is that if you do need them as such, you need a cap at the input, otherwise the source will go below zero, but the opamp has unipolar supply. It may also be a cause for a wrong simulation output.